# best way inner join symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a lot of times 2 or more entities who are related to.

For example:

entity avance(): with attributes: id, userId, questionnaireId, questionId

entity questionnaire: id, name, questionsNbres

entity questions: id, question, responseA, responseB, responseC, correctResponse

When I call an avance entity, it is complicated to find the questionnaire name attribut, I have to do a lot of foreach to find the correct one. The same for all the questions that are related to.

I'm sure that a best solution exist, for example with a inner join, but I don't know how to do this in symfony.

Comment: you can use QueryBuilder to do joins (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builderl) or even use DQL (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql)

Answer (score 0):

You get two tools that responds to theses problems.

You can setup annotations in yours models to automate data fetching. This is the [JoinColumn](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) annotation

However, because the JoinColumn usually over-fetching, my recommandation would be to put in place a custom [repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes), it allow to create complex query with joins.

In your case, I think you need a left join aka "extends my datas, with another data set".